# Ren'Py with Renpygame for Android

Tags: python, android, pygame, renpy

I have this game which I have coded in python with pygame.

When I launch my game through the renpy launcher, it works just fine.

When I emulate my game through the renpy android emulator, it works just fine.

When I go through each of the build steps (install sdk, configure, build package, install package) it completes successfully.

The package is installed on my connected android device.

When I open the game on my android device, it says:
"ImportError: No module named renpygame."

When I build the game and play it on my desktop I don't have this problem.

I'm guessing somehow renpygame is not getting included in the package when I go through the build process in renpy for Android, but I don't know why or how to fix it. I'm not even getting an error message, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I e-mailed PyTom, the creator of Ren'py, and he responded back instantly:

"Edit the rapt/blacklist.txt file, and delete the line that says **.py. "

It worked! Thanks, PyTom.